# Identifying priors and posteriors in a narrative laid out in prose

Tags: probability, probability-theory

**Problem**

Explain the following Sherlock Holmes saying in terms of conditional probability, carefully distinguishing between prior and posterior probabilities: *"It is an old maxim of mine that when you have excluded the impossible, whatever remains, however improbable, must be the truth."*

**Attempt**

Initially, Sherlock Holmes may have a few possible theories of what happened, collectively labeled $A$.
Mr. Holmes being a great detective, $P(A)$ is close to $1$, but he would like to chase the most likely account of what may have happened.
After some deliberation, he discards theories he deems least likely, collectively labeled $B$. Thus, what must be the truth according to Mr. Holmes is 
$$P(A \cap B^{c}) = P(B^{c})P(A|B^{c}).$$

The prior in this problem is $P(A)$, and the posterior, *however improbable*, is 
$P(A|B^{c})$.

- Does my interpretation make sense?
- What is your interpretation?

Comment: Holmes discards what he considers "impossible," not what he "deems least likely."  This is an important difference.  (Of course, humans are notoriously bad at distinguishing "impossible" from "unlikely," but that is another discussion.)

Comment: @sasquires This would make the posterior, the way I have defined it, the same as the prior. Seems to me that if Holmes is discarding strictly impossible events, he is not changing his initial beliefs.

Comment: My interpretation is more like the following.  Holmes initially brainstorms some set of ideas, $A$.  Then he uses reasoning based on the evidence at hand, $E$, to show that some subset $B \subset A$ is impossible, i.e., $P(B|E)=0$.  Now, $P(A|E) = P(B|E) + P(A - B | E)$ (where $-$ indicates a set difference).  This reduces to $P(A|E) = P(A - B | E)$.  If we add the prior assumption $P(E)=1$ (i.e., the evidence is real and Holmes believes it), then this gives us $P(A)=P(A-B)$.  If he also assumes that $P(A)=1$ (i.e., he has brainstormed every possibility), then this gives us $P(A-B)=1$.

Comment: The way I interpreted this was that at first we have $A$ the set of all events. Let $B \subset A$ define the impossible events. Let $E \in A$ be any given event. Then $P(E|B^c) = 1$ because the fact it is not impossibles makes it certain.